# How to synchronise threads without using any synchronisation methods?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I was asked in an interview that it is required to print numbers 1 to 3 in a sequential order by 3 threads without using any synchronisation techniques.

I think that we can access the thread id to find out which thread it is and keep a flag associated with this thread in a structure which can be set to true this thread in currently accessing the data.

Interviewer laughed at this idea. So obviously it is wrong.

What can be the way to achieve this task?

Comment: Using `Atomic<int>` to increment and print? If threads and numbers are not tied.

Comment: `print numbers 1 to 3 in a sequencial order by threads` how many threads ?

Comment: Pass 1, 2, and 3 as parameters to the thread and sleep for that number of seconds before printing the parameter? But @LouisGo is probably the correct answer. EDIT: Or is it? There could be a thread switch between the `operator++` and the `std::cout`.

Comment: How do they define "synchronization method?"

Comment: I had explicitly asked for  mutex locks and condition variables. so they said no to them. So can spinlocks be considered a default synchronization technique?

Comment: This sounds like a really strange question... "Synchronize threads without using synchronization", what? Do you know if this is something you might have to do in production code for some reason, or if it is a pure: "Think out of the box and do wacky stuff, brain teaser"?

Comment: @Frodyne Depends on the context. If you're applying for a real-time programming job, interviewers might want you to be familiar with scheduling strategies that facilitate this (see my answer). It is not of much use for general programming, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Create thread A
Thread A prints '1'
Thread A creates thread B and exits
Thread B prints '2'
Thread B creates thread C and exits
Thread C prints '3' and
exits
```

No explicit synchro required, prints 1,2,3 in order using three threads, is a totally pointless exercise.

Answer (score 3):

You use a single-core scheduler with lock-free [ICPP scheduling strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_ceiling_protocol). This is not covered by the C++ stdlib, but POSIX has an API for it.

Since you are on a single core, only one thread runs at any time, and ICPP guarantees that it will never be preempted while holding a resource by another thread that wants to access that same resource. Therefore, you don't need thread synchronization.

Comment: I think it is the only post that answers the question. All other suggestions with atomics, locks, mutexes etc. are actually synchronization methods.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought, but context switch might happen between `std::count` and `++i`.

```
class Solution{
  private:
     atomic<int> i(0);
  public:

// func 1 2 3 are identical.
     void func1(){
         std::cout<< ++i;
     }

     void func2(){
         std::cout<< ++i;
     }

     void func3(){
         std::cout<< ++i;
     }

}
```

Second thought, using atomic with spin lock, so execution order should be fixed.

```
class Solution{
  private:
     atomic<int> i(1);
  public:
     void func1(){
         std::cout<< i;
         ++i;
     }

     void func2(){
         while( i != 2);
         std::cout<< i;
         ++i;
     }

     void func3(){
         while( i != 3);
         std::cout<< i;
         ++i;
     }

}
```

Comment: While the increment operations are atomic there's no guarantee as to the order in which the values are output.  `std::cout << ++i;` is really just `++i; std::cout << i;` .

Comment: @G.M. Spin lock is added, should it be safe?

Comment: @G.M. No, that's not correct. The return value from `++i` _will_ be a copy of the value _after_ the preincrement and that's the value that will be used. In your example `i` may have been incremented again before it gets used..

Comment: Spin lock isn't a synchronization method? No default synchronization methods are allowed.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl You mentioned "no mutex locks and condition variables", so I'm not sure if spin lock is lock as well. I edit the answer to leave my first and second implementations.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, good point.  Same basic problem though.

Comment: They basically said no synchronization techniques are allowed.

Comment: I like the second version, but note that the tests should be `i != 2`, `3`.

Comment: @G.M. "_Same basic problem though_" - Yes, I agree.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl, Re, "no synchronization techiques are allowed." If they'd been interviewing me, I would not have been afraid to say that the question made no sense as asked. Anything you that could possibly do to guarantee that several threads make certain things happen in a certain order would count as a "synchronization technique." That's what "synchronization" _means_. If I was the one asking the questions, I wouldn't necessarily be looking for a "correct answer." I would be looking to start a dialogue in which we talk about threads, and you show off what you know about them.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I am guessing that they were expecting me to invent my own  synchronization techinique.

Comment: @LouisGo Thank you for showing another way of doing it.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl It's good to see an in-depth answer from flyx. :)

Answer (score 1):

for fun:

Emit them by time?

for example

print 1 at 00:01
print 2 at 00:02
print 3 at 00:03

If you set the time interval big enough that the chance they run out-of-order is lower than a bit flip in the system, then you are good.